# How can I browse public repositories on Bitbucket?

Tags: tortoisehg, bitbucket

I'm learning to use TortoiseHG and want to pull from someone else's repository to see what a real, working one looks like -- how often they branch and merge, how much code they lump into each commit.

Comment: What type of question is this? Obviously to browse public repos, you search for them. -1

Comment: @PTBG If you click on the bitbucket tag few of the questions are about "programming" as in writing code. Yet there are 450 of them.

Comment: @Cygwinnian I posted after trying the searches "bitbucket 'example repository'", "bitbucket view public repositories," "repository on Bitbucket", "browse bitbucket". No dice.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The amount of repositories must be quite large and I don't think there is a way to browse them.

1. There is a search function at

   ```
   https://bitbucket.org/repo/all
   ```

   that you might use to look for repositories about a certain topic.
2. The [main page](https://bitbucket.org/) has a a few examples at the bottom ([TortoiseHg](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/overview) among them). You might need to log out to see this list.
3. Finally, searching for `Home site:bitbucket.org` in Google shows a large list of repositories and I imagine other such searches might be useful.

Comment: All three parts of this answer work great, including the part about logging out that was preventing me from seeing the home page. Thank you very much for looking at my question!

Answer (score 5):

It appears this search functionality is not yet available. See [Bitbucket issue 2934](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-2934)

Another way to browse all repositories is to search a common word that is not on their stopword list.  Searching for "fork" returned 6288 repositories (as at 10-May-2013). See [fork Bitbucket search](https://bitbucket.org/repo/all/followers?name=fork)

If you find a better keyword let me know and I will update this comment.

Comment: The 2nd link is broken